# Issue with drag + drop sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm currently having a bit of an issue with my sortable JQuery list. I have multiple columns of "assignments" that the user is able to drag and drop to different dates. The drag and drop function seems off at times and does not allow me to drag and drop an item anywhere in a new column.

Currently - this is my JQuery Sortable function:

```
$( ".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    scroll: false,
    distance: 7,
    distance: 7,
    placeholder: 'placeholder1',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});

$( ".connectable_list2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    scroll: false,
    distance: 7,
    distance: 7,
    placeholder:'placeholder2',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

Here is the link to my fiddle so you can test out the issue yourself: [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rs7bv59n/10/) 
For example, I am not able to drag the last list element of the first column into the first list element spot in the next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do draggable + sortable for this kind of thing:

```
 $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
     scroll: false,
     distance: 1,
     placeholder: 'placeholder1',
     tolerance: 'intersect',
     revert: true
 });

 $(".connectable_list1 li").draggable({
     connectToSortable: '.connectedSortable',
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/rs7bv59n/12/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the draggable function does not seem to solve the problem. A main example of the issue I'm having is that I am not able to drag one list element to the first spot in a different column.